# Eclipse View Descriptor removed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin project with some custom views, but lately every view has an error in the runtime:

```
 !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-07-19 20:24:24.597
 !MESSAGE Removing part descriptor with the 'com.test.ResourceChanges' id and the 'Resource Changes' description. Points to the invalid 'bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView' class.
```

I compared the code to an almost empty example with the sample view, where the view can be shown, and all code looks good. Also, other projects for dependencies are working well.
On the other side, the sample view does not work in the project either.

An example plugin.xml entry:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
    <view allowMultiple="false" category="com.test.category" class="com.test.ResourceChangesView" icon="icons/Icon.png" id="com.test.ResourceChanges" name="Resource Changes" restorable="true">
    </view>
    <category id="com.test.category" name="Changes"></category>
</extension>
```

The views extend org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart, but as I said even an empty view will not get registered.

Comment: I had this problem in some plugin B after doing heavy renamings within our plugins (including plugin.xml files). A view that was opening fine started failing with the same message you show. The view was linked to its class in plugin.xml with the following: class="com.mycompany.plugin_A.ExecutableExtensionFactory:com.mycompany.plugin_B.MyView", i.e. it was using guice injection (with plugin B depending on A) and the problem was that ExecutableExtensionFactory wasn't loadable anymore. By trying to open the view programmatically (IWorkbenchPage::showView) we obtained a better error message.