# Removing part descriptor error on exported Eclipse product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created an Eclipse product that opens a view. When I launch it through the .product file, everything works fine and the view opens but when I export it and launch it through the new .exe file I get this issue on startup:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 2 0 2019-03-28 15:48:23.160 

!MESSAGE Removing part descriptor with the 'views.myView' id and the 'test myview' description. Points to the invalid 'bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView' class.
```

Because of this, the view doesn't open on the exported product.I didn't change any of the dependencies so I can't figure out why this appears to be happening.

Comment: That class is in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plug-in - has that been included in the exported product?

Comment: yes that is in there as well, this problem seemed to occur out of nowhere, the exported product used to work as well previously.

Comment: Just saw this is basically a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199282/eclipse-view-descriptor-removed, unfortunately no answers on that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a new project from scratch and copy & paste all the folders/files in there. I am still unsure as to what caused the issue.

Comment: Had the same issue.. hat to recreate the project also. Looks 1:1 the same in Eclipse but now the error is gone and it works. I guess we found a rare bug here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the "build.properties" was the problem.

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/,\
               ...
```

the "source" path was not specified, and it occurred the error that removes part descriptor and some things.